# Prove every map from the projective plane to the circle is nullhomotopic

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces, fundamental-groups

Prove that every continuous map $f:P^2\to S^1$, where $P^2$ is the projective plane, is nullhomotopic.

I think I need to use the fact that $\pi_1(P^2) = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and covering space theory. The map $f$ induces a map $f_* : \pi_(P^2) = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \to \pi_1(S^1) = \mathbb{Z}$, but I don't see why this map is trivial.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is $P^2$ the projective plane? In that case, $\pi_1(P^2)=\mathbb{Z}/2$. HINT: What are the maps $\mathbb{Z}/2 \to \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @FredrikMeyer's suggestion is what you need. See also a [related post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77891/null-homotopy-of-a-map-to-the-circle).

Comment: I'm learning covering space and this is an exercise for that.I think I should use things related to covering space but $\pi_1(\mathbb P^2)=\mathbb Z_2$...ah,maybe I see how to prove it.

Comment: @bgins Thank you but $f_*(\pi_1(\mathbb P^2))$ is not trivial,so I can't find a lift of f from $\mathbb R \to S^1$

Comment: @Fredrik Meyer Is there a contractible covering space of $S^1$ whose fundamental group is $\mathbb Z$?

Comment: @JiangnanYu No, because all contractible spaces have trivial fundamental group.

Comment: @JiangnanYu: Why would you say $f_*(\pi_1(\mathbb{P}^2))$ is not trivial?

Comment: @JoeJohnson126 Sorry,I mean we can't see directly that $f_*(\pi_1(\mathbb P^2))$ is trivial

Comment: @Fredrik Meyer Hi,I can't figure out the proof,could you tell me how the maps $\mathbb Z/2 \to \mathbb Z$ work?

Comment: If you are having trouble characterizing $\operatorname{Hom}_\mathbb{Z}(\mathbb{Z}_2,\mathbb{Z})$, you should probably go back and brush up on commutative algebra before you continue studying algebraic topology ...

Answer (score 19):

As Jim pointed out, it's not enough to show that $f_*$ induces the trivial map on fundamental groups.  To finish it, we can proceed as follows.  Let $p\colon \mathbb R\to S^1$ be the covering projection.  Since $f_*(\pi_1(P^2))=0$ (as Fredrik showed), it's clearly contained in $p_*(\pi_1(\mathbb R))=0$.  So, this means there is a map $\tilde f\colon P^2\to\mathbb R$ such that $f=p\tilde f$ (Proposition 1.33 in Hatcher).  Now, $\mathbb R$ is contractible so we have a homotopy $H\colon P^2\times I\to \mathbb R$ such that $H_0=\tilde f$ and $H_1$ is constant at some $x_0$.  But then $pH$ is a homotopy from $p\tilde f=f$ to $p(x_0)$ meaning that $f$ is null-homotopic.

Answer (score 7):

I'll assume by $P^2$ you mean the real projective plane and I'll also assume you know that $\pi_1(P^2)=\mathbb{Z}/2$.

Now, every map $f:(X,x_0) \to (Y,y_0)$ of based topological spaces induces a map between their fundamental groups $f_*:\pi_1(X,x_0) \to \pi_1(Y,y_0)$.

Now, $\pi_1(P^2,x_0)=\mathbb{Z}/2$ (and in fact, we may forget about the base point, since $P^2$ is path connected). Also, $\pi_1(S^1, x_0)=\mathbb{Z}$. So a continous map $f:P^2 \to S^1$ induces, by the above paragraph, a map $\mathbb{Z}/2 \to \mathbb{Z}$. Torsion elements are sent to torsion elements, but $\mathbb{Z}$ is torsion-free, so the only possibility is that $\mathbb{Z}/2$ is mapped to zero. So every map $f:P^2 \to S^1$ induces the trivial map on fundamental groups. <strike>This means that $f_*$ is homotopic to the null map.</strike> **EDIT: See SL2's answer below for the conclusion.**

(regarding maps $\mathbb{Z}/2 \to \mathbb{Z}$: What happens to $1 \in \mathbb{Z}/2$? The map must satisfy $f(1+1)=f(1)+f(1)$, but $f(1+1)=f(0)=0$ , so $2f(1)=0$, hence $f(1)=0$.)

Comment: You also need that the higher homotopy groups of $S^1$ vanish. Normally it is not sufficient to check $\pi_1$. (Equivalently, $f$ lifts to a map to the universal cover, which is contractible in this case.(

Comment: @Jim Thank you for pointing that out.  I found [this](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/2672/whitehead-for-maps) relevant MO post which says that even if $f_*\colon \pi_k(X)\to \pi_k(Y)$ is 0 for all $k$, it isn't true that $f$ is necessarily null-homotopic.  You really do need a covering space argument to finish this.

Comment: @SL2: And *thank you* for pointing that out.

Comment: @JimConant : Thanks for pointing out my error. I've edited my answer accordingly (with a reference to the answer below).

Comment: Thanks Fredrik Meyer,now I know $\mathbb Z/2 \to \mathbb Z$could only be a trivial map :)